# How can I determine when an AD group is 'available' for ACLs after creating it in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I've run into an issue in a script I've been writing that will call thousands of lines of input and must often create new AD groups and apply them to new folders.  The issue is that often times, the AD groups aren't 'ready' to use (i.e., ready to be called in an ACL creation command) after they're created unless I call a sleep for a prohibitively long period of time due to the number of iterations the script must make and the amount of time this would add to its run.  That is, if I call a 20 second sleep, it will probably work in most cases but if I have 2000 groups to create, that's over 11 hours that this operation adds to the running of this script.

Before anyone asks, the large number of AD groups is due to a broad front-end data migration to a platform in a different domain, and is a requirement.

I've tried entering a 'start-sleep -s 1' loop until the group is non-null before proceeding, but an 'unusable' group is not necessarily $null.  I've tried entering the same type of loop and checking to see if 'Get-QADGroup' returns a SID, and only continuing when it returns an actual group name, but when immediately continuing, I've found that sometimes those groups still aren't 'available.'

I read an article somewhere that (I believe) discussed being able to do this creation directly on a Domain Controller (still via PS), though it wasn't terribly specific and even if I do have permission to do that (I'm not sure at the moment), I'd be hesitant unless I was certain of what I was doing (I'm a Data Storage Admin by trade, I just get stuck with a lot of AD management stuff).

Anyway, I'm still googling and trying to work with the Windows team but was hoping someone might have come across this problem in the past where a long sleep wouldn't cut it.  Thanks so much in advance for any suggestions!

Mike

EDIT: To add some context to this, here is what my script needs to do:

1. Take an input file consisting of an existing source folder and a corresponding new destination folder on a fresh filesystem.
2. Create the folder on the destination side
3. If the permissions of the source folder differ from its parent, create new groups in a different domain, with names based on the name of the destination folder.
4. Add the newly created groups to the destination folder ACLs
5. Extract any and all permissions from source folder groups/accounts and add them to the destination folder's new group.

All of the logic seems to be in place, but I'm stuck waiting too long for the groups to propagate in AD after they're created.

Comment: Why not do all the group creations first, then go back and do the folder permissioning after they've had time to propagate?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  That was and is my fall-back plan.  The only reason I was avoiding this method (which certainly should work) is that the script is looking into folders at a depth of 5 directories, and creates groups according to folder names.  If there was to be a user-driven change to a subfolder name on the source, I'd be worried that upon a second iteration of the script (this time _applying_ the new groups), the logic in the script that associates groups with folder names would break--though maybe I could add some logic to handle that.

Comment: In that scenario, I'd grab and save the folder structure first, and work out of that for both passes.

Comment: On second thought the issues I mentioned might be problematic regardless of how this is implemented...

Comment: Ya, I may have not have a choice but to approach it that way--we'll see.  Thanks for the replies!

Comment: If it's driven by the directory structure, and they're allowed to make changes to the structure while the script is running, it may be the only way to get anything like a fix on a point-in-time state.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see it is to create the new folder then add the group to the new domain then apply the group to the folder permissions and apply the ACLs. The best way to create the groups is with powershell.

I had a similar issue in which I was creating the groups and applying ACLs faster then the new group could be replicated on our domain.

The way I solved it was to create the folder then create the groups in AD with new-QADGroup. and I took the results of the new-QAD group and plugged that in a variable then when I assigned the group to the folder I used that variable to assign the groups SID directly to the folder and set ACLs. This allowed me to create the permissions on the folder immediately before the group fully replicated. Once it did replicate the SIDs on the folder and on the AD group would match and the group would then properly give permissions on the folder.  Here is the code I used:

```
$newGroupObject = New-QADGroup -ParentContainer $ParentOU -Name $newGroupName -SamAccountName $newGroupName -GroupType 'Security' -GroupScope 'Global' -Description $ShareDesc
$newGroupSid = New-object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($newGroupObject.sid)
$Acl = Get-ACL $newFolderPath
$newAccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($newGroupSid ,"Modify","ContainerInherit,Objectinherit","none","Allow")
$Acl.AddAccessRule($newAccessRule)
Set-Acl $newFolderPath $Acl
```

Hope this helps!